# simple fetch request missing headers for a while (chrome only)

Tags: fetch

I've got this weird bug I can't track down.  It only happens in Chrome/Edge not Firefox.  I'm doing a simple cross-origin `fetch(url)` request with no options.  If I do it right after the page loads, Chrome doesn't send the Origin header (as well as a number of other headers like Accept, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, etc.)

But if I wait a bit (like a minute), then it works fine.  Request headers are all normal.

How do I make this fetch request reliably send the Origin header in Chrome?

I have tried adding the option `{mode: 'cors'}` but there is no change.  Requests in the first few seconds are missing the header, and later requests work fine.  It happens in development and production so is unlikely to be related to network speed.

It is an image and there is an `<img>` on the page with the same URL.  The `<img>` is loaded before the first fetch attempt.

[image: request with missing headers]

Comment: Javascript, right?

Comment: So you have an `<img src="https://example.com/someimage.png">` tag on your site and then you do a `fetch("https://example.com/someimage.png")`? May it be possible that the requests without `Origin` header where initiated by the `<img>` tag and not by `fetch`?

Comment: Javascript, right

Comment: @derpirscher no it's not possible.  I can see a new request in the network tab every time I press the button.  I am also filtering for Fetch/XHR requests.  The img request is also there with `Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8` and many other headers